# jquery.html() loads the codeigniter view - only one line file

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm loading a view, `extra.php`, into `#extra` div via jquery command:

```
$('#extra').html("<?php $this->load->view('extra'); ?>");
```

`extra.php` is a long file, and `jquery.html()` loads only a single line of code

for example, it loads fine:

```
<table><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></table>
```

but it doesn't load at all:

```
<table>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
</table>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Does it matter if it loads it in one line? I mean, why you display it it will display just fine, or are you planning something else with it?

Comment: Is the issue that it will only load the *first* line, or that it loads the entire page as *one* line?  Are you getting all of the data or is something not getting loaded?

Comment: if you are wanting closer look at source, do it in a browser console where DOM is all neatly packaged in expandable tree, indentation/formatting in source isn't critical

Comment: @charlietfl - That assumes the OP is getting all data, just not tidy via "view source".  Is that due to how codeignitor outputs html, or jquery's `.html()`, or more likely that the `extra.php` in question is outputting all as one line?  Just curious if you know where the minifying is taking place.

Comment: @Anthony lack of line breaks in php would do it, jquery will retain formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I found some extra solution on codeigniter board, it's simply hilarious:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/219780/

: )

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each line that is output from the view, that way you can pass a multi-line string to the function. To escape, you just need to append a `\` to the end of each line so that you would have the following:

```
$('#extra').html("<table>\
<tr>....</tr>\
<tr>....</tr>\
<tr>....</tr>\
</table>");
```

You can see it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/gWcmU/).